# Use Evolution to back up Gmail "Sent folder"

Tags: evolution, gmail

I want to retrieve (initially via POP) my Gmail account mails, but the idea is just to keep a backup of those mails. But Gmail "Sent" mail is retrieved and put altogether with received mail into my Evolution inbox.
How can I get mails in my Gmail "Sent" folder from Evolution?

(if I could get my Gmail labels, too, that'll be great, but it's not a primary goal)

Comment: I would (move to IMAP) just moved over to Thunderbird and it would have been alot easier with IMAP

Comment: Sorry, but I did not really undertsand that last comment... my English is not as good as I would like. Can you explain that better (for a dumb like me :) )?

Comment: Using IMAP as the protocol rather than POP3 can fix this.  By using IMAP, you can specify the location on the remote server as the "Sent Mail" folder.  This will then allow all future sent messages to be stored in the "Sent Mail" folder located on Google's mail servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i'm assuming your using IMAP

open edit --> preferences
select your account and press edit
goto defaults tab
change sent messages folder to: [Gmail]/sent mail

this will automatically add sent mail to your gmail account from now on.
just drag old sent mails onto this folder

Luri asked which would be best, POP or IMAP...

best is a matter of preference here. IMAP will treat all your gmail labels as seperate folders. Staying with pop, with all your sent and received mail in your inbox you could just create a filter locally. to create a filter goto: edit --> message filters. check its set to incoming. click add. for your sent mail: Sender, is, you@gmail.com, move to folder, destination folder. ok. Now goto your inbox press CTRL+A then CTRL+Y, this will apply the filter. play around a bit with filters for the rest of your email.

Comment: As I commented in Allan's answer, I'm using POP right now, but I suppose I can switch to IMAP, if that makes a big difference....

Comment: It does when you want to keep multiple devices in sync. [here](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75725)

Comment: click the here in above comment for a link to gmail help pages to read more about IMAP.

Comment: Actually, I'm just "downloading" my mails to keep as a backup, in case Gmail fails and erases info or my account gets hacked or.... who knows. So it's not a matter of syncing several devices, but of downloading mails in some "organized" way. From what I've seen: POP won't retrieve labels, and all mails (sent and received, as I don't have any custom Gmail folder) are equally treated (and so they're put into my Evolution inbox). What I'd like to have in my "backup copy" is labels and a separate folder for my "Sent" Gmail folder. In this scenario, is IMAP better or is there a better way?

Comment: beter is a matter of preference here. IMAP will treat all your gmail labels as seperate folders. Staying with pop, with all your sent and received mail in your inbox you could just create a filter locally. to create a filter goto: edit --> message filters. check its set to incoming. click add. for your sent mail: Sender, is, you@gmail.com, move to folder, destination folder. ok. Now goto your inbox press CTRL+A then CTRL+Y, this will apply the filter. play around a bit with filters for the rest of your email.

Answer (score 0):

your sent emails if they are pop should be here `/home/luri/.evolution/mail/local/sent`

[image: picture of sent mbox file]

the one with no extension is the mbox file

hope this helps

Comment: That's my locally sent mail folder.... I meant my Gmail's sent folder

Comment: what are you using POP or IMAP?

Comment: POP...... i could change it, tho.... (I guess)

Answer (score 0):

My requirements are:

1. I want to download and keep a backup on my PC and at the same time syncing Gmail (leaving the mail on the server too)
2. I want to reflect the changes (read/unread/reply etc except delete maybe) at one to another.
3. I want Gmail **labels**
4. I want to be able to export import my email (with attachments) to any other Email client in future

**Will Evolution be able to do this? On IMAP? Is selecting "Automatically synchronize remote mail locally"** does the trick?

@Allan: Which theme are you using? Looks nice, I would like to try if doesn't involve much hassle :-)